# Что понимается под пространством имён в спецификации HTML5?

Tags: html, xml, html5, xhtml, namespace

Выдержка из спецификации:

> In HTML documents, elements in the HTML namespace may have an xmlns
>   attribute specified, if, and only if, it has the exact value
>   "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml". This does not apply to XML documents.

Переводится примерно: "В HTML документах элементы в HTML-пространстве имён могут иметь атрибут xmlns, если он имеет точное значение "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml". "

И тут я понял, что вообще ничего не понимаю. Я думал, что для html нет понятия пространство имен.

Ссылка **HTML пространство имен** в спецификации ведет на список:

```
Пространство имён HTML это: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
Пространство имён MathML это: http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML
Пространство имён SVG это: http://www.w3.org/2000/svg 
Пространство имён XLink это: http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink 
Пространство имён XML это: http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace 
Пространство имён XMLNS: http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/
```

И я совсем не могу понять, что такое имеется ввиду под пространством имен в данной спецификации? Пространство имен html ведет вообще на xhtml спецификацию. Причем тут html5 и xhtml? И как это связано с пространством имен?

Что значит фраза "элементы в HTML-пространстве имён могут иметь атрибут xmlns"? В html пространстве имен это где? И как работает этот атрибут в html5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Про атрибут xmlns

По поводу xmlns, в том же [тексте](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes), сразу после приведённой в вопросе цитате сказано следующее:

> Note: In HTML, the xmlns attribute has absolutely no effect. It is
>   basically a talisman. It is allowed merely to make migration to and
>   from XHTML mildly easier.
>
> Заметка: В HTML, xmlns атрибут не имеет никакого эффекта. Это просто
>   талисман. Он лишь позволяет проще выполнить преобразования в и из
>   XHTML документов.

С этим разобрались, xmlns в HTML нам не потребуется. Его конечно можно использовать для HTML-элементов, но это не имеет смысла, так как для всех структур в HTML документе уже есть предустановленные значения "пространства имён", список которых приведён в вопросе, и изменить их на другие значения никто не позволит. Проще говоря, нижепревидённые примеры равнозначны:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
```

А вот так `<html xmlns="что-то своё">` уже не получится, так как xmlns попросту игнорируется, и html всё равно будет располагаться в пространстве имён "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", как было сказано выше.

### Про пространство имён

По аналогии с именами классов, пакетов и т.п из языков программирования, пространство имён позволяет отличить один элемент от другого, когда они имеют одинаковое название, но принадлежат разным пространствам имён. Где это может произойти в HTML? Например когда мы используем svg в html:

```
<svg>
   <a xlink:href="/"><text x="0" y="20" fill="green">Ссылка в SVG</text></a>
</svg> 
<a href="/">Ссылка в HTML</a>
```

И нам потребовалось изменить размер шрифта у ссылки в svg. Просто написать в стилях `a { font-size: 1.5em }` уже не получится, так как это правило применится и к обычной ссылки тоже. Вот здесь на помощь приходят возможности CSS по работе с пространствами имён. Для этого в CSS выполним такие действия:

1) Используя ключевое слово @namespace указываем наименование "приставки" пространства имён, с каким мы будем иметь дело:

```
@namespace svg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg);
```

Заметка: адрес пространства имён для SVG взят из спецификации, а вместо svg можно использовать другое наименование.

2) Теперь с помощью приставки svg можно обратиться непосредственно к метке `<a>`, которая расположена в `<svg></svg>`, с помощью специального синтаксиса CSS:

```
svg|a { font-size: 1.5em; }
```

### Итог

1. Атрибут xmlns в HTML не нужен.
2. Спецификация за нас определила названия пространств имён для конкретных структур HTML, XML, SVG и их элементов.
3. Для того чтобы в CSS получить доступ к конкретному элементу с использованием пространства имён необходимо использовать форму `namespace|css-selector`, предварительно дав наименование для пространства имён с помощью @namespace.

Comment: понятно. т.е. по сути пространство имен в атрибуте - это никакая не ссылка, а просто строка (набор символов), которая уже давно определена? и это в общем-то нужно для выделения конкретного элемента при совпадении имен, например, если применяется несколько языков в одном документе?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев да, это строка, а вид ссылки выбран для гарантии уникальности данной строки. И да, пространства имён нужны для разграничения элементов, когда в одном документе несколько разметок.

Comment: А как программа понимает тот или иной неймспейс? Под каждым неймспейсом должны скрываться какие-то правила чтобы программа знала какой набор правил или инструкций применять.

Comment: @MaximPro правил нет, это обычная строка, просто название.

Comment: @edem нет я все понимаю что строка это и есть namespace. Но ведь должны же быть описаны правила поведения при конкретных namespace. И как программа поймет мой namespace? Когда я даже никаких особых правил не предоставлял. Какой толк от этих строк если это просто строки?

Comment: @edem когда мы говорим про namespace у нас в голове появляется ассоциация с конкретной областью где валидны конкретные определения. Но а как мы можем проверить валидность этих терминов без словаря или документа который описывает конкретное поведение?

Comment: @MaximPro пространство имён, это как имя модуля (пакета), в котором расположены другие "переменные" (в html это html-метки например: div, p и т.д). Поэтому каждый волен избирать своё наименование для namespace; другое дело, что для многих областей, как html уже придуманы свои наименования, которые и нужно использовать. Список же предопределённых имён есть в спецификации.

Comment: @edem ТС привел список этих имен (namespace) для разных областей. А каков их смысл? Ну не буду я указывать этот namespace что-то вообще поменяется?

Comment: @MaximPro судя по формулировке вопроса, для вас нет, в противном случае да, если используете svg разметку, например, на html странице, тогда там необходимо разделение, дабы различать к каким тэгам применять правило (пример 2 из ответа).

Comment: @edem но вы в html разметке явно не указываете svg namespace. Почему?

Comment: @MaximPro потому что они уже указаны по-умолчанию.

Comment: @edem и как программа понимает что мы обращаемся к svg тегу а не к html тегу? Учитывая что там и там тег <a>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80608/discussion-between-edem-and-maximpro).